# Stick a header to the top of the screen

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I want to use a sticky header, and on a normal screen (PC/Laptop, etc) it works fine. But on the phone it doesn't work when I zoom in.

I think it happens, because the phone just shows a part of the website, while the page still has the same height as when not zoomed in.

I just have this CSS:

```
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Is there any way to make my header stick to the screen-top, instead of the page-top?

[image]

Comment: difference between screen-top and page-top ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/yxFBynJ Here is an image that should make that clear. The screen is the phone screen, when zoomed into the page

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp are you like this

Comment: without your html (enough code to run and demonstrate your issue) you'll be lucky to get an efficient answer. clarify your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position: fixed`

It will take screen height

Answer (score 0):

Change sticky to fixed, that way your header should be always on the top of the screen and I suggest you to read this for more information https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position2

Comment: That still didn't stick the header to the screen. when I zoomed in, the header sticked to the page, but not to the screen itself

Comment: Are you sure ? However, there's another solution, you can use bootstrap templates.